# Clojure ring-cors/wrap-cors setup

Tags: clojure, cors, clojurescript

I'm using [ring-cors](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors) and trying to pass a cors-policy for the (wrap-cors) function. This is what my code looks like:

```
(def cors-policy
  {:access-control-allow-origin [#"http://localhost:8080"]
   :access-control-allow-methods [:get :put :post]})

(def dev-handler (-> #'japi/routes
                     wrap-reload
                     wrap-params
                     (wrap-cors cors-policy) ;; <- Here
                     wrap-json-response
                     (wrap-defaults api-defaults)
                     push-state/handle))
```

This results in an error:

> No value supplied for key: {:access-control-allow-origin
> #{"http://localhost:8080"}, :access-control-allow-methods #{:get :post :put}}

Looking at the source code for [(wrap-cors)](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/cors.cljc#L192) it looks like the error is coming from [trying to apply (hash-map) to my cors-policy map](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors/blob/master/src/ring/middleware/cors.cljc#L157). It seems like I cannot pass a map definition but instead I have to pass the keys/values explicitly when calling (wrap-cors). Any ideas to work around this?

I've tried `(apply hash-map cors-policy)` in the repl and that works fine, however when passing a dummy handler such as `(wrap-cors identity cors-policy)` this again results in the same error.

**Edit:** *cfrick's answer is correct, note however that I had to remove shadow-cljs' (push-state/handle) handler at the end of my dev-handler definition for my setup to work.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrapper uses a "pattern" that is sometimes seen and focuses on
"human consumption" of the function.  It takes the "rest" of the
arguments and turns the pairs of it into a map.  This is already "meh"
for humans and is utterly bad for machines (e.g. to pass as arguments).

You have to do the call it like this:

```
(wrap-cors $handler :a 1 :b 2)
```

So the easiest way from here would be:

```
(def cors-policy
  [:a 1
   :b 2])

(apply wrap-cors $handler cors-policy)
```

Or if you want to stick with the map (IMHO a good approach), you have to
flatten the map beforehand.  e.g.

```
(apply wrap-cors $handler (into [] cat cors-policy))
```

But with the use of the threading macro `->` this becomes harder to do
now (`->` is just a macro and the resulting code would be `(apply $handler wrap-cors ...)` which is unintended.

So at this point I'd add my own `defn` that just takes the handler
again.  E.g. something like

```
(defn cors-wrapper
  [handler config-map]
  (apply wrap-cors handler (into [] cat config-map)))
```

Comment: This dance is no longer needed in Clojure 1.11 https://clojure.org/news/2021/03/18/apis-serving-people-and-programs